# Why we need to specify absolute path in Bottle + uWSGI?

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi, bottle

I'm developing a Bottle application.
My program reads configurations from configuration (.cfg) files and also using template (.tpl) files.

But when I host my app on nginx using uWSGI, it cannot find the files (given relative paths to the project)

What is the possible solution??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using relative paths, store an absolute path based on the *current* module path:

```
MODULEPATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)

template = open(os.path.join(MODULEPATH, 'templates/sometemplate.tpl').read()
```

`__file__` is the filename of the current module, `os.path.dirname(__file__)` is the directory the module resides in.

You should never rely on relative paths in Python code; the current working directory is not changed when running a python program.